# how to concatenate two string in grafana metrics

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable

how to append two variable inside vector,

```
[30d] should be replaced with [${days}${consd}]
```

my actual query (part of the query)

```
method=~"[[Method]]",le="+t"}[30d])) * 100
```

here i want replace the 30d with two grafana variable say one

```
grafana variable "days" as text box defaulted with 40, which will be edited by user.
grafana variable "consd" as constant defaulted with value "d".
```

now i need to update the above query like below but its  not working its just taking only the first value.

method=~"[[Method]]",le="+t"}[${days}${consd}])) * 100

Answer (score -2):

method=~"[[Method]]",le="+t"}[${days}d])) * 100